# Visual Studio deploy fails with "The method or operation is not implemented"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remotely debug a Windows 8.1 app on an x86 tablet.

The Remote Debugger is started on the Tablet, but every time I try to deploy the app to the Tablet, the Visual Studio output window shows this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: $REDACTED, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  $REDACTED-> C:\Users\$REDACTED\bin\x86\Debug\$REDACTED.exe
2>------ Deploy started: Project: $REDACTED, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>Error: The method or operation is not implemented.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also, the Remote Debugger on the tablet prints `Failed attempt to connect from $REDACTED`

Comment: Are you able to deploy locally (not on the tablet)? Also - make sure that both machines are using the same account, and there aren't any firewall settings blocking the remote debugger.

Comment: @MariaGhiondea-MSFT Yup, a local deploy works fine. I'll check the firewall settings tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

Changing remote machine (VS 2015 Remote Debugger settings) from `No Authentication` to `Windows Authentication` fixed the problem for me.